# Sphinx not recognized as a command within Poetry project Python

Tags: python, dependencies, virtualenv, python-sphinx, python-poetry

I am trying to set up Sphinx documentation for my Python project using Poetry as the package manager. However, when I run `poetry run sphinx-quickstart` in my project directory, I receive the following error message:

```
'sphinx-quickstart' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Here is my `pyproject.toml` file:

```
[tool.poetry]
name = "testing-project"
version = "0.1.0"
description = ""
authors = ["User  <user@gmail.com>"]
readme = "README.md"
packages = [{include = "testing_project"}]

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.9"
Sphinx = { version = "4.2.0", optional = true }
sphinx-rtd-theme = { version = "1.0.0", optional = true }
sphinxcontrib-napoleon = { version = "0.7", optional = true }
cython = "^0.29.35"

[tool.poetry.extras]
docs = ["Sphinx", "sphinx-rtd-theme", "sphinxcontrib-napoleon"]

[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core"]
```

Tree Structure:

```
.
├── Testing_project
│   ├── testing_project
│   │   └── __init__.py
│   ├── docs
│   ├── poetry.lock
│   ├── pyproject.toml
│   └── tests
│       └── __init__.py
└── README.md
```

I have already ensured that Sphinx is installed by running `pip show sphinx` and confirming its presence. However, it seems that the `sphinx-quickstart` command is not recognized within my Poetry project. I also do not want to use a `pipenv` or a `poetry env create` virtual environments since I will be utilizing Docker for that.

Can someone help me understand why I am encountering this error and how to resolve it?

Comment: Poetry is meant to be used with the virtual environments it creates itself. It is possible to use Poetry with an already existing virtual environment. Do you have a virtual environment? Why do you have a Pipfile if you say you do not want to use pipenv? What does Docker have to with this? Docker and virtual environments are not the same thing one can not replace the other. -- So do you have a virtual environment or not (at least locally)? If yes, how did you create the virtual environment? How do you use it? Where is it?

Comment: Mb the pipfile was not supposed to be there, I have updated the code. Since docker created a virtual environment I did not want to use a poetry virtual environment since I have a separate container for each process docker.  Isd it not possible to use poetry without a virtual environment?

Comment: "_Isd it not possible to use poetry without a virtual environment?_" If I recall correctly, it is possible. I recommend you check Poetry's documentation. But then I am not sure calling commands such as `poetry run ...` makes sense. -- And also, using (Docker) containers does not necessarily mean you do not need a virtual environment. It all depends how the Python interpreter is set up. For example if the Python interpreter already has system packages, then you should use a virtual environment. This rule is true inside and outside containers.

Comment: Did you run `poetry install -E docs` to install the dependencies listed in the `docs` extra?

Comment: thank you that works, I forgot to do that.